# PHP: Remove javascript events from html

Tags: php

Is there any way to remove js events like 'onload', 'onclick',... from html elements in PHP?

For example if `<a (onclick)="alert('hi')">Link</a>` is given, the desired output should be `<a>Link</a>`.

I did it this way:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($request->request->get('description'));
$nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('*');

foreach($nodes as $node)
{
    if ($node->hasAttribute('onload'))
    {
        $node->removeAttribute('onload');
    }

    if ($node->hasAttribute('onclick'))
    {
        $node->removeAttribute('onclick');
    }
}

$dom->saveHTML();
```

However I'm not sure if it's a safe way to that, because if later a new js event will be created the chance that I'll forget to blacklist it is real.

Comment: Have you considered a whitelist approach, where you only allow specific attributes and nuke all the rest?

Comment: Note that this won't affect any JavaScript code elsewhere in the document.  The element could still have click handlers, just not ones from inline attributes.

Comment: Yes, if not inline js is present in the document, it should also be removed. But therefore I'll remove everything between <script> tags.

Comment: Yeah, I also thought about whitelisting but curious if there are other ways that I don't know about

Answer (score -3):

You should build a Javascript method that does this for you, and can apply it after the body loads, because php code executes at page load and you can't check later in the document if theres other event, until it loads again.

Comment: I need to do it in PHP, not in JS